# Prove that alteast one of the real numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n$ is greater than or equal $\dots$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question:**

> Don't declare this as duplicate, the duplicate question is just the first part
>   of a two part question.

49.) Prove that alteast one of the real numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n$ is greater than or equal to the avg of these numbers. I already proved this.

50.) Use Exercise 49 to show that if the first 10 positive integers are placed around the circle, in any order, there exist three integers in consecutive locations around the circle that have a sum greater than or equal to 17.

**My Attempt:**

49.) (Proof by contradiction) Supposed all $a_i < A$, $A$ is the average, adding all $a_i$ should be less than $nA$,
$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ...+ a_n < nA$$

Dividing $n$ on both sides,

$$A < A$$

Which is a contradiction.

I'm pretty confident of my proof for 49, 50 is where I'm having trouble.

50.) Don't know where to start, I took the average of first 10 positive integers, which is 5.5. I'm lost from here.

Comment: Hint: Consider the set of sums of three consecutive numbers in the circle. The sum of all them is $3(1+ \dots + 10) = 3 \cdot 55$, hence their average is $3 \cdot 5.5 = 16.5$.

Comment: How is $3*(1+\dots+10)$ the sum of all the 3 consecutive sum? Can you pls elaborate on that further?

Comment: Never mind, I pictured it in my mind. Thanks.

Comment: [My solution here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864863/wheel-of-fortune-problem) may help.